# Print UTF-8 characters in cmd using python

Tags: python, windows, utf-8, character-encoding, cmd

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print "ÆØÅ"
```

When running the above script in Windows 7 with python 2.7.3 using `cmd`, `powershell` or `cygwin`, I get this output:

```
├å├ÿ├à
```

The file is a UTF-8 file and works fine in my text editor.
How can I make it print "ÆØÅ"?

Comment: Does `print u'ÆØÅ'` work?

Comment: Did you try `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 python yourscript.py`?

Comment: @msvalkon That worked perfectly and `from __future__ import unicode_literals` works too. @ThomasOrozco I have no idea how to do that in `cmd`.

Comment: Well then there you go :)

Comment: Windows UTF8 printing in the console is notoriously troublesome. You need to use the correct codepage (65001), for Python versions before 3.2, add support for that codepage to Python, and use the correct font to display unicode glyphs.

Comment: Odd that it prints something for you. It would just crash everything when I tried to print some greek letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force unicode when printing:

```
print u'ÆØÅ'
```

Answer (score 5):

Bit late to the party here, try

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
print "ÆØÅ"
```

Comment: Using the `from __future__ import unicode_literals` is useful in an interactive python session. Thank you for it.